# XSL apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XSL code, that gives me output only with 1 line. How i can do it with all rows? This is my INPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odds xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sport name="Soccer">
<region name="Europe">
<competition name="UEFA Champions League">
<event name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
<market name="[Full Time] Handicap" suspended="false" id="21905549" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" inRunning="false">
<outcome name="Real Madrid (-3.5)" id="49954038" price="16"/>
<outcome name="FC Bayern München (+3.5)" id="49954039" price="0.98"/>
</market>
</event>
</competition>
</region>
</sport>
</odds>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@suspended"/>

<xsl:template match="market[@suspended='true']"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="market">
<xsl:variable name="handicap" select="substring-before(substring-after(outcome/@name, ' ('), ')')" />
<market name="{@name}" expiry="{@expiry}" inRunning="{number(@inRunning='true')}" id="{concat(@id, $handicap)}">
<selection price="{outcome/@price}" id="{outcome/@id}" name="{outcome/@name}" handicap="{$handicap}" />
</market>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odds xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sport name="Soccer">
<region name="Europe">
<competition name="UEFA Champions League">
<event name="Real Madrid - FC Bayern München">
<market id="21905549-3.5" inRunning="0" expiry="2014-04-23T18:45:00Z" name="[Full Time] Handicap">
<selection handicap="-3.5" name="Real Madrid (-3.5)" id="49954038" price="16"/>
</market>
</event>
</competition>
</region>
</sport>
</odds>
```

But as you can see, in my input i have 2 outcome lines. I think i need to add somewhere  but i dont know where. Thank you

Name templates:

```
<xsl:template match="@name[. = '1X']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/Draw</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = '12']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[. = 'X2']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Draw/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
<selection price="{outcome/@price}" id="{outcome/@id}" name="{outcome/@name}" handicap="{$handicap}" />
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="outcome"/>
```

and then add a template

```
<xsl:template match="outcome">
  <selection price="{@price}" id="{@id}" name="{@name}" handicap="{substring-before(substring-after(@name, ' ('), ')')}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Assuming you have your three templates for the `name` attribute also in the stylesheet I would edit them and add the name of the element you want to transform to the match pattern, for instance

```
<xsl:template match="outcome/@name[. = '1X']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/Draw</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="outcome/@name[. = '12']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Real Madrid/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="outcome/@name[. = 'X2']">
<xsl:attribute name="name">Draw/FC Bayern München</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

then I would change the template of the `outcome` element to

```
<xsl:template match="outcome">
  <selection handicap="{substring-before(substring-after(@name, ' ('), ')')}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Last my question. I have template, where if name = 12, the name should change to Draw. I already have this template, but how i can connect it with my template outcome?

Comment: We would really need to see your template, if it is also for the `outcome` element then make sure you add it with `<xsl:template match="outcome[@name = 12]"> <selection price="{@price}" id="{@id}" name="Draw" handicap="{substring-before(substring-after(@name, ' ('), ')')}" /></xsl:template>` after the template above. To avoid warnings, you can also set a priority  `<xsl:template match="outcome[@name = 12]" priority="5"> <selection price="{@price}" id="{@id}" name="Draw" handicap="{substring-before(substring-after(@name, ' ('), ')')}" /></xsl:template>`.

Comment: i added my name templates